# undefined method 'id_tag' for ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In my CrawlProduct class I want to get the id_tag from the table ProductInfo:

```
class CrawlProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :crawl_link

    css_id = self.crawl_link.domain.product_infos.id_tag
end
```

The table `CrawlProducts` has a foreign key `crawl_link` and the table `CrawlLinks` has a foreign key `domain` which comes from the table `Domain` of course. And ProductInfo belongs to domain.

```
class CrawlProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :crawl_link 
end   

class CrawlLink < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :domain
        has_one :crawl_product
end

class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :crawl_links
        has_many :product_infos
end

class ProductInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :domain
end
```

But at the end, I always receive the following error:

```
undefined method `id_tag' for #<ProductInfo::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x0055d72e423640>
```

How can I access the `id_tag`? There is no column missing as far as I know.

**Edit**: after the answers I get a different error.

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `id_tag' for #<CrawlProduct:0x0055d72fcd9fe0>
```

I don't know why I'm getting this problem. Here is how I create the id_tag:

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
   domain = Domain.create(domain: 'https://www.example.com')
   product_info = ProductInfo.create(domain: domain, id_tag: 'some content')
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're accessing `product_infos` incorrectly. You need to specify which one you want, and then access the id_tag from it.

Rails is correctly telling you that

```
undefined method `id_tag' for #<ProductInfo::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x0055d72e423640>
```

because the relationship is has_many.

If you wanted to just access the first one the database pulls out (in no specific order, unless you specify), you could just do

```
css_id = self.crawl_link.domain.product_infos.first.id_tag
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.crawl_link.domain.product_infos` is a collection of instances, so you can't call instance methods on it, to call it on each item you should either iterate collection with `each` or collect ids with `map`. To collect just ids without creating instances you can use `pluck`:

```
self.crawl_link.domain.product_infos.pluck(:id_tag)
```

Answer (score 1):

**self.crawl_link.domain.product_infos** will return a group of objects so, you cannot retrieve id_tag(a field) from a collection.

Instead you can use,.

```
class CrawlProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :crawl_link

    def some_action
      css_ids = self.crawl_link.domain.product_infos.pluck(:id_tag)

      (or)

      css_ids = self.crawl_link.domain.product_infos.map(&:id_tag)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm still getting an error. I edited my question

Comment: add the action in which you are using these lines

Comment: are you calling `css_id` directly from the model?